# Does the Alexandrov angle define convex functions along geodesics in CAT(0) spaces?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, non-positive-curvature

Let $X$ be a CAT(0) space and suppose $a,b,c,d\in X$ satisfy
$$
 \max\{\angle_a(b,c),\angle_a(b,d)\}<\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
Let $\gamma:[0,\ell]\to X$ be the geodesic with $\gamma(0)=c$ and $\gamma(\ell)=d$.

Is it true that for all $t\in[0,\ell]$,
$$
\angle_a(b,\gamma(t)) \leq \max\{\angle_a(b,c),\angle_a(b,d)\}?
$$

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "no" even for 3-dimensional Hadamard manifolds.
Moreover, implication
$$\measuredangle[a\,^b_c]<\tfrac\pi2 \ \&\  \measuredangle[a\,^b_d]<\tfrac\pi2\ \Rightarrow\ \measuredangle[a\,^b_x]<\tfrac\pi2$$
does not hold for any $x\in [c,d]$.
Let me explain it in a nondirect way.

Choose a generic 3-dimensional *Hadamard manifold* $M$; that is, a simply connected manifold with nonpositive sectional curvature.
Suppose the implication holds in $M$.
Consider two sets $A$ and $B$ defined by
$$A=\{\,x\in M\mid \measuredangle[a\,^b_x]\leqslant \tfrac\pi2\ \text{or}\  x=a\,\}$$
$$B=\{\,x\in M\mid \measuredangle[a\,^b_x]\geqslant \tfrac\pi2\ \text{or}\  x=a\,\}$$
Since the $M$ is uniquely geodesic, both $A$ and $B$ are convex.
Therefore
$$S=A\cap B=\{\,x\in M\mid \measuredangle[a\,^b_x]= \tfrac\pi2\ \text{or}\  x=a\,\}$$
is a geodesic hypersurface.

On the other hand generic 3-dimensional Hadamard manifolds do not have geodesic hypersurfaces; see ["About every convex set..."](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15189) by Alexander Lytchak and me.
Therefore, we get a contradiction.

Comment: I think there’s a typo: the definitions of $A$ and $B$ are the same…

Comment: @HJRW fixed, thank you.